# Routing not working with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm working on one of my friend's half-built React Project. I'm trying to route my react-app with react-router-dom. The components inside the `<switch>` are not working. Here's my

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Main from './components/Main';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import ProcessInput from './components/ProcessInput';

// Import react-router-dom
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';


function App() {
  return(
    <Router>
        <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Main} />
                <Route path="/process" component={ProcessInput} />
            </Switch>
            <Footer />
        </div>  
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

> Main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Slider from './Slider';
import Card1 from './Card1';
import Card2 from './Card2';
import Prompt from './Prompt';

class Main extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <main>
                  <Slider />
                  <Card1 />
                  <Card2 />
                  <Prompt />
               </main>  
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Main;
```

The `<Header />` and `<Footer />` which are outside the `<Switch>` are showing anyways as intended. But, I want the Main component to be loaded as a root component (Launcher).

There are no errors on the console.

Please help me get to know what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: From the shared snippet I see no reason why `Main` wouldn't be matched and rendered by the `Switch`. Is nothing from `Main` rendered? Have you tried rendering something simple like plain text from `Main` to see if it's *that* component or something external to it? Does the `ProcessInput` component render on "/process"? If possible can you try creating a *running* codesandbox that accurately reproduces your issue and link it here in your question?

Comment: No, there's absolutely nothing from the Main is rendered. I tried a simple <h1> in ProcessInput.js and tried to route myself to /process. It's not rendering that as well.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code you posted as well.

Comment: Have you tried to remove `main` tag?

Comment: Yes, I did. It's still not working!

Comment: Are you navigating via links/etc within the app? Does manual URL entry work? What are you doing to produce the issue (i.e. reproduction steps)? Please do try to create a codesandbox that reproduces the issue that we may inspect and live debug in.

Comment: I'm on it......

Comment: Hey Drew!

The irony is, it's perfectly working in codesandbox and not in my browser. I imported my actual project from Github and checked it. I restarted the deployment server. I tried to run it in Incognito. Still not working!!! Can you believe it?

Comment: Can you still share it, perhaps in reviewing it we may see any "trouble spots" or potential issues.

Comment: Hi Drew, I've added you to my codesandbox. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route path="/" exact>
<Main/> 
</Route>
<Route path="/process"><ProcessInput/>
</Route>
```

This is the old way to do it. You can try this

Comment: I gave it a try too.

Comment: No, not really!